# SQL Server : FOR XML set root attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml

How do you set the root attribute to a column in a `FOR XML` in SQL Server?

For instance, if you have 3 columns like 'First Name', 'Last Name', and 'Person' and you wan the output to be something like

```
<root type="person">
    <first Name/>
    <last name/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select 
    'person' as '@type'
    /*
    rest of stuff goes here...
    */
From someTable
FOR xml path('root')
```